# The shell/terminal does not allow/show my password

Tags: sudo

I am trying to install gfortran from a shell/terminal, I write `sudo apt-get install gfortran` and then in the next line appears `sudo password from romulo`. But when I try to write the password the letters of **the password does not appear** in the shell, I can't write any letter. This occurs when I try to install any program. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

When you enter your password at a `sudo` prompt, no letters or other symbols appear. Type your password correctly, hit enter, and everything should work fine.